# SpringBoot TestNg and PowerMock

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, testng, powermockito

I am using spring boot, TestNG and PowerMock.

I have extended `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and also created `ObjectFactory` as a part of power mock. All the bean which are getting autowired are set as `null`. Also getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer
```

Comment: Could you post some code so that I can recreate this in my local?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after a few hours maybe a day, I've decided to migrate to Junit (just the tests that use PowerMock). And everything worked fine. It seems there is an issue with PowerMock + TestNG + Spring. I was looking at their Issue Tracker and there are a lot of complaints related to this problem. I know that I didn't give you a solution, but as a palliative, it could be fine.

Comment: Any idea if this works in JUnit 5? We are also facing quite a bit of limitation with Spring Boot (v 2.0.0.RELEASE) and TestNG.

Comment: Hi, we didn't try Junit 5. We've only used version, 4.12. So, I couldn't tell you exactly. Sorry.